# How can i create an object without specify the value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a new migration, but if i dont send that attribute in the payload the new object have the flag nil, but it have to be false, what is going on here?

```
def change
    add_column :sections, :flag, :boolean, default: false
end
```

i need an object with flag= false

edited 1:

if i add `null: false` at my migration i am getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:
        PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "flag" of relation "sections" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Do you *ever* want the field to be nil?

Comment: @DavidGrayson flag it have to be true or false, not null

Comment: @DavidGrayson i should work in the model? or this migration should be enought

Comment: The migration is usually the correct place to specify allowed values and default values of columns.

Comment: Could you try specifying `default: 0` instead of `default: false`?

Comment: @DavidGrayson there is not changes with 0, i am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `default: 0`. In previous version like 4.2, migration needs 0 or 1 to be able to set default false/true value.

However, from the 5.1 version, you can directly use true/false like you're doing `default: false`.

Let me know if that worked or not.